# How to get original clipart from this scanned picture?

Tags: quarkxpress, pagemaker

We are recreating a magazine from 1993.
Original source files are lost and we want to get everything in best possible quality.
This is an image scanned from the original magazine. It most likely comes from a clip art database of the DTP program used to make this magazine. It can't be newer than 1993.
But we don't know what DTP they used.
I tried Google Images and Tineye but no luck

Can you identify this clip art? Or the DTP program? Perhaps it was QuarkXpress, PageMaker or Publisher.

[image]

Comment: In 1993 it could also be analogue and might never have been a digital file. Would perhaps be possible to determine by looking with a magnifying glass or a microscope to see if there is evidence of pixels. Is this really a scan and not a photograph? It looks distorted. The woman seems very long and the paper she's holding looks a bit skewed as well. Also have this image been processed? Why is there no sign of halftone screening? Seems unlikely for it to be an 7-8 ink print.

Comment: @Wolff I am sure it's digital. It was a magazine about computer games full of screenshots. And I am 90% sure this is a vector clip art.

Comment: If you say so I believe you. But just because it's a computer game magazine doesn't mean *parts* of the graphics can't be analogue. Back then it could be a jigsaw puzzle of mixed media taped together by hand on films before exposing press plates.

Comment: 93 would have *possibly* been more Xpress than Pagemaker. Especially if magazine circulation was higher. While both were used, XPress was king and more common for high-end agencies/in-house teams. Back then, Pagemaker was to Xpress what Xpress is to InDesign today. And there's a possibility it came from any one of several "clip art" **books** which contained photostat artwork to scan or pasteup. Clip art in the early 90s was really still analog a great deal (not exclusively though). If you *really* need it, I'd recreate it today. Chances are that'll be quicker than trying to find it.

Comment: If you can get a good scan of the image, it should be possible to auto trace it in Illustrator.

Comment: @Scott I can recreate this image but quite likely we will recreate more issues of the magazine and there will be more cliparts to be done.

Comment: That is, unfortunately, going to be a common issue for anything on the cusp of the digital era... it's a hodgepodge of what may or may not be available digitally. As I posted, "clip art" is an area where, unless you were part of that *rare* group which spent a few hundred dollars for a stack of 3.5" or 5.5 floppy discs which came in big 3-ring binders with disc sleeves... you used $20 books and scanned/pasted up images. Many of those, now dated, clip art packages may never have been converted to digital assets. I know in the early 90s I did far more scanning from books than pulling from discs.

Comment: @Scott I see your point. I didn't even know there were analogue clip arts. However the guys behind this magazine were fairly "modern" and were the first ones on the local market to add a cover diskette and then a cover CD. Do you know of any popular digital clip arts libraries back then?

Comment: I can't recall any names of books specifically. To be fair, it really all depended upon the company.. some jumped on board and bought digital art without a problem. Other companies stuck with traditional ways and saved the money. Point is that not all art *was* digital. And the art which was digital was more popular and *far* less "dated" in appearance. CDs weren't even that common for art in the early 90s. It was still primarily diskettes. Don't let the fact that the magazine provided a CD mean that much. The magazine may have been progressive for its time. Art packages are quite different.

Comment: Stock art had actual physical catalogs. Massive books. One had to look through thousands of pages to determine what you wanted.... then call to purchase and wait for delivery, often via disk and FedEx/mail. There was no searching or even really any online resources. It was all still very manual much of the time until the mid to late 90s

Comment: Looking at this drawing again I'm getting more convinced that it could be hand drawn and not vector. Maybe drawn directly on film? Small inconsistencies in the stroke width, small overlaps. Doesn't look like the way you would draw vector digitally. But it could be nice to see a scan at higher resolution of some of the details. Hard to tell what's going on. Can you share which magazine this is?

Comment: @Wolff It is a magazine from Poland so most likely you never heard of it and I can't say much about it at this point. Perhaps you are right an they drew this. I don't have higher quality scans at the moment or the original paper version. I should have them in a few weeks, perhaps. I found an old interview with the guy who did DTP/graphics (and was the deputy editor-in-chief) for the mag and a year before he used Ventura and Corel Draw for another mag.

Comment: OK, maybe you can even get in touch with this guy and ask for some tips?

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, it might be easier to simply recreate this. It would be quicker than trying to find something that may have never existed in a digital format. As others have suggested, in 1993 a lot of work was still being done using traditional analogue techniques, essentially photographing clip art books. I can attest to that as I was working in the print industry at that time. Also the style of the clip art looks retro even for 1993. It looks more like something from the 1950's or 60's.

Anyway, here's how it could be approached, if you're interested in going down that route.

A bit of pixel manipulation in Photoshop to fix the stretched distortion, and remove the colours. Then in Illustrator you could auto trace the black lines, do manual colouring, redrawing lost details, and you could get quite a decent result. Obviously, not so easy if you don't have the skills.  You could always hire someone to redo it.

Here's a quick example I made for fun. Vector (left), Original (right).

[image]